# Persisting a preexisting Entity Instance is ignored by the persist operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was going through the JPA 2 specification and found two statements that sounds contradictory **to me**.

> 1. "If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation." - Pg 76
> 2. "The EntityExistsException may thrown by the persistence provider when the persist operation is invoked and the entity already exists." - Pg 129

The statement 1 says something that sounds different from statement 2. So, my question is what is the difference between "preexisting managed entity" and "entity already exists"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 2.1 of the spec, chapter 3.2.2, you can find this about the `persist()` operation:

- If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation. However, the persist operation is cascaded to entities referenced by X, if the relationships from X to these other entities are annotated with the cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL annotation element value or specified with the equivalent XML descriptor element.
- If X is a removed entity, it becomes managed.
- If X is a detached object, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time

So, `persist()` will ignore the entity if it's a **managed** object. It can throw an exception (or throw it, or another one, later) if the entity is a **detached** object.

First case:

```
Foo foo = em.find(Foo.class, 1L);
em.persist(foo); // ignored
```

Second case:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setId(1L);
em.persist(foo); // may throw an exception
```

Comment: @ JB Nizet Please read the section on "Summary of Exceptions" in the Entity Operations chapter or check the below link on EntityExistsException; It says "Thrown by the persistence provider when EntityManager.persist(Object) is called and the entity already exists."  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html

Comment: @Aceghn That's an incomplete description of when the exception is thrown. The spec is the reference, and it clearly makes a difference between a detached entity and a managed one.